# What is the correct datatype for storing hashed passwords in mysql?

Tags: mysql, hash, passwords

I plan to hash passwords on my server using SHA512 before inserting them into my database. What datatype should I use for the password column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends if your encrypted password may be binary or not : if yes, use blob or varbinary, otherwize char, varchar or text will do it.
[reference : mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html)

Comment: Thanks, Aif. Does MySQL have it's own hash function? If that is true, I don't have to use a ColdFusion function to hash the password! I can user a built in MySQL Function, correct? And if I did use a MySQL, would the password be binary or not? Am I right in thinking I can hash the password string using MySQL before the insert statement?